# GWT Mobile Framework for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, gwt, mobile

I am trying to find a suitable GWT Mobile Framework to use with Windows Phone 7. All the ones I have found rely on webkit browsers i.e. GwtMobile,M-Gwt.

Anyone know of a Mobile GWT Framework that works with the IE on WP7?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no HTML mobile frameworks that support the WP7 metro theme. However, some of the iOS themed frameworks do support WP7. The latest versions of jQuery Mobile work just fine on the WP7 browser, and there is a GWT / jWueryMobile framework available called [jqm4gwt](http://code.google.com/p/jqm4gwt/).

Comment: Hi ColinE. Typing "jqm4gwt and windows phone" in google, your answer is the only one I could find. Due to your answer, I've decided to use jqm4gwt. Thanks a lot!